# Java 7 JRE installed but not enabled on OSX Mountain Lion

Tags: java, macos, osx-mountain-lion, java-7, java-6

Java on Mountain Lion is giving me some issues.

- When I load a website with Java embedded I get the 'Blocked Plug-in' notification.
  [image: Java version]
- Clicking it prompts me to download and install the latest Java JRE. Fair enough, I did that.
- After running the latest Java 7 JRE installer (multiple times), when I check the Java Control Panel from within System Preferences I can see that supposedly only Java 7 is installed. (both in the 'User' as well as the 'System' Tab)

[image: Java control panel]

- However when I check in the terminal, I still only see Java 6:
  [image: Java terminal version]

And I still get the 'Blocked Plug-in' notification. I also made sure to check that my Safari security settings allow Java.

As far as I can tell I still have Java 6 installed and (I am assuming) that's what's being used by the terminal/browser. So my question is, what can I do to configure java 7 to be used instead of 6? This would mean that if I run 'java -version' in the terminal I would see '1.7.0_10' and not '1.6.0_37'.

Comment: Use http://apple.stackexchange.com/ for this question.

Answer (score 0):

This could well be related to the current news item that the US CERT has recommended disabling Java 7 until a patch for the most recent sandbox hole can be published on Tuesday.

Apple may have disabled the plugin to protect you.

[Here is the bulletin.](http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/625617)  But if you Google "java 7 problem" you'll get many popular press items.

You said: "Hmm, possible, but I still think when I run 'java -version' it should show up as 1.7.0_10, regardless of any security measures on apple's part, and not 1.6.0_37, so something is not configured correctly."

Not true.  Installing an Oracle JRE doesn't make java available at the command prompt.  Only installing the JDK does.  You have the Apple Java left over because you upgraded to Lion and ML from Snow Leopard (right?).  Now Apple has reached out through its black list mechanism and disabled your Oracle Java 7 by declaring it a "virus."  So you're left with what you had.  Makes total sense.

Comment: Hmm, possible, but I still think when I run 'java -version' it should show up as 1.7.0_10, regardless of any security measures on apple's part, and not 1.6.0_37, so something is not configured correctly. I also tried completely disabling the security measures in the Java Control Panel, and no change.